# how to change SITE AREA constant dynamically in CI-BONFIRE?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, bonfire

I am new to bonfire, I am developing a system that incorporates three users

1. Admin
2. Clients
3. Agents

I have changed login destination for each above mentioned users in bf_roles table in database, but the issue is that the SITEAREA constant defined in constant.php file under application folder,is set to admin
i.e

```
define('SITE_AREA', 'admin');
```

I want to define sitearea according to the respective users
i.e for clients it should be

```
define('SITE_AREA',clients);
```

now with the default site area set to admin, I get this address whenever I login using clients credentials

```
http://localhost/pbx/index.php/admin/
```

How to dynamically change the site area for each user?

Answer (score 0):

Since `SITE_AREA` is a view related constant. *i.e.* It's used only in views.
It's definition can be moved to a later time in the application lifecycle, to a time before a view is rendered.*e.g* in your base controller:

- Define a variable in your base controller that references the value of which `SITE_AREA` to use.
- Selectively rename references to `SITE_AREA` in your view templates to the new variable name. ✌️

Comment: sir thanks for showing the concern...i am still confused,my site area is defined in constant.php and is set to admin panel

Comment: Sir btw can you help me in understanding the bonfire..?as i am new to bonfire development

Comment: Bonfire provides a list of libraries, modules, helpers and templates to build CodeIgniter projects faster. You want to begin with understanding request-response flow in CodeIgniter.